# Grub problem after upgrading Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, upgrade, synaptics

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 along Win7.

I have tried to upgrade Ubuntu via Synaptic.

After upgrade, Grub screen does not have Ubuntu in its List. You can see shot in below :

[image]

Please tell me what am i missing here?

Any helps would be awesome.

Comment: How exactly did you upgrade Ubuntu? This is very weird for simply upgrading Ubuntu.

Comment: I can not go to Ubuntu and check what I exactly did now. But I just went to Synaptic and checked all checkboxes up  and then apply them. After upgrade, Grub does not have Ubuntu in list items. It was all things I remember...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a GRUB update you **should** execute on a virtual terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

It updates grub.cfg to reflect the new changes in the system.
Since you are excluded from the system, you can try to use a rescue CD/DVD to edit grub.conf: follow the [official guide](http://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/AmministrazioneSistema/Grub/Ripristino) is always a good idea, it will solve!

Bye, good luck.

Comment: I followed [official guide](http://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/AmministrazioneSistema/Grub/Ripristino) successfully. Grub screen changed to [purple style](http://up.vbiran.ir/uploads/IMAG0118_39562138114130111509.jpg), but Ubuntu item does not add to Grub list yet :(. Any ideas?

Comment: I expect an upvote man ;-) (follow you conscience) 
You can follow http://ubuntuguide.net/manually-addingremoving-entries-to-grub-2-menu or use `sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.cfg` to edit grub.cfg manually. The /etc/grub.d/ files are scripts, so I recommend you to edit only the pre-existent `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` script: if you do a mess simply edit or remove it. After **each** edit run update-grub. Now there is my grub.cfg: http://pastebin.com/cdwMP9mZ 
**DO NOT COPY-PASTE, it's not useful**, because my cfg might be different: an advice is to watch the section with "ubuntu" in it.